# Me retorna null al ejecutar mi wsdl en c#

Tags: c#, webservice, soap, net

Actualmente quiero obtener un xml al ejecutar uno de los metodos que me proporciona mi wsdl, el codigo que tengo para eso es el siguiente:

```
    xxxx.execute ejecutar = new xxxxx.execute();
    ejecutar.modo = "1";
    xxxx.ServiceNow_GetTimeCardMode servicio = new xxx.ServiceNow_GetTimeCardMode();
    servicio.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
    servicio.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    servicio.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxx", "xxxx");
    xxxxx.executeResponse respuesta=  servicio.execute(ejecutar);
```

El problema surge cuando llega  esta linea:

```
 santecmxdes.executeResponse respuesta=  servicio.execute(ejecutar);
```

Ya que ese elemento contiene dos propiedades que se deberían llenar, sin embargo todo el objeto se llena con la palabra `null` y por ende sus propiedades. Ya lo probe en el programa de SOAP UI para ver si me retornaba algo y si lo hizo, no se si me falte algo de la configuración para que el retorno en mi codigo sea correcto.

Comment: es un servicio creado en asp.net ? o sea tienes un asmx en la url. El Execute es el webmethod que expone el servicio porque esta algo raro la funcionalidad que expone, instancias un `xxxx.execute` he invocas un `servicio.execute()` no se quien diseño eso pero no se inspiro mucho en darles nombre algo mas significativos

Comment: @LeandroTuttini el xxx.execute yo lo oculte por motivos de seguridad, pero el metodo si es execute y no es un asmx es un wsdl creado mediante service now.